# IIS loading image resources fails using non-standard Port

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have a  PHP web application hosted in IIS. The problem I have is that some image resources can't be loaded because I'm using a non-standard port 81.
But in developer tools I can see that the GET Request using the default port 80.

[image]

There are 2 rules already in the web.config but I'm not sure for what purpose.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                 matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                 ignoreCase="false" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                 matchType="IsDirectory"
                 pattern=""
                 ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

How can I make this work with any port bound to the webapp?

EDIT:

Here is what I get in the FailedReqLogs:

```
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification 16 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)
```

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: I edit the error stack in my post. If I modify the get request in developer tools and add the right port to the address then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check the code of your HTML.

If it's referencing a FQDN without the extra port added then that will be your problem. You shouldn't hardcode anything

Comment: It's not my code so I thought I could solve that problem with some IIS configuration. It's weird because it works with an Apache Webserver.

Comment: So your code doesn't reference "www.google.com/pagehere" for example?

Comment: I just took a look and I can see this: <img src="<?php echo Help::getStaticBaseUrl(); ?>/images/icons/info.png" alt="" />

Comment: That's why, The getStaticBaseUrl() is giving you your localhost without the port

Comment: actually I can't there is no index file with that many lines. Additionally, the whole application is encrypted with ioncube so I can't even debug that properly.